# Open shell script in a new window from another shell script

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

Currently using Raspbian

If I type `lxterminal -e ./Desktop/test.sh` it will open `test.sh` in a new window and do it's thing. The problem is when I call `test.sh` from another script inside a LOOP and IF statement, a new window opens and nothing happens.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

STARTED=0

#sleep 5

while [ 1 ]

do {

START_TIME="$(date +'%H%M%S')"
if [ $START_TIME -ge 073000 ] && [ $START_TIME -le 193000 ] && [ $STARTED -eq 0 ]
    then
        STARTED=1
        lxterminal -e ./Desktop/test.sh
        echo "$(date +"%m/%d/%y - %l:%M:%S %P")" - "started"

elif [ $START_TIME -ge 193001 ] && [ $START_TIME -le 072959 ] && [ $STARTED -eq 1 ]
    then
        STARTED=0
        killall firefox-esr
        echo "$(date +"%m/%d/%y - %l:%M:%S %P")" - "stopped"
else
    echo "$(date +"%m/%d/%y - %l:%M:%S %P")" - "Still within time limits"
    fi

sleep 5

}

done
```

Comment: If you want the script to continue immediately instead of waiting for the window to close, use `lxterminal -e ./Desktop/test.sh &`

Comment: Hello, I added & and it still opens another window that does nothing.

Comment: It's the opened window that does nothing? That sounds more like a `test.sh` problem

Comment: @the other guy , if you type the command outright, it works, calling it from inside another script, you get a window that does nothing.

Comment: Are you running that other script from the same directory as when you type the command?

Comment: @thatotherguy Yes.

Comment: Maybe you need to specify the working directory (--working-directory=DIR).  And start your terminal with nohup and '&'.  So your line would be `nohup lxterminal -e ./Desktop/test.sh --working-directory=SOMEDIR &`